# Google App Engine authorization

Tags: java, google-app-engine, redirect, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am developing a Google App Engine Web Application in Java that requires to access to the user's Google Drive space.
When I try to use the local server for debugging, the servlet which has the duty of managing the credentials builds an authorization url and try to redirect the user to the page that asks the user to grant the application the rights to access to the drive folder, but this page never appears.
When I deploy my project in the GAE space, it just work fine.
I tryed to add a new clientID that has a redirect to:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

and javascript origins to:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

but I can't still get it right.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could get the redirect to the authorization page using my local server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take for instance i have this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Oranges</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.OrangesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>oranges</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oranges</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To call the oranges page, i will do

`http://localhost:8888/oranges`

So in your case, replace `oranges` with what ever your authorization url is

Comment: I edited the redirect URL as you suggested, but it's still not working. 
I really can't figure out why in my Google App Engine space the authorization page is shown correctly and in my local server it fails to do the redirect. The redirect URLs that I use for the GAE space and the local server are identical, the only difference is that the first uses https while the other http and, of course, the addressed host.

Comment: This is just speculation now, but can you try using https for both?

Comment: I tryed, but the local server doesn't support the https protocol.
Do you have any other ideas that could make the redirect work?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unfortunately even changing the port number it's still not working

Comment: My hands are tied man/woman :D Try going back to the beginning and make sure you follow and monitor the steps closely.It's always something silly that messes everything up.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I will try to make a brand new project and see if I can get it right.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Awesome.Good luck.Remember,patience.